# How do I configure Apache so a vhost without SSL will not be answered by the first vhost with SSL?

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

When Apache (v2.4) assigns a request to a vhost, it will use the first matching ServerName/ServerAlias across all  configs, but if nothing matches it will use the first  (ignoring the ServerName/ServerAlias definitions).

> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/details.html
>
> The first name-based vhost in the configuration file for a given
>   IP:port pair is significant because it is used for all requests
>   received on that address and port for which no other vhost for that
>   IP:port pair has a matching ServerName or ServerAlias.

The problem I'm having is on a shared host with a control panel. Some domains have a SSL certificate and others do not. When someone tries to access their domain without a certificate using HTTPS, I'd rather return a 404 instead of someone else's content after a security warning.

I've tried setting up a *:443 vhost that matches ServerAlias * and that didn't work. I have successfully setup a catch-all vhost matching each IP:443 individually, but this means I'll have to remember to edit this file when an IP is added to the server.

Is there a way to configure explicit ServerName/ServerAlias matches only so vhost **only** matches specific hostnames, or is configuring a higher priority "catchall" vhost with a shared SSL certificate the only way to workaround this issue?

Comment: More importantly, why hasn't the domain got its own SSL already?

Comment: Of course that would fix it as long as every domain owner chooses to install a free certificate. Unfortunately not everyone wants SSL, though. I think SSL is best but also this behavior does feel broken to me. I’m not sure why Apache wants just any vhost even if the hostname explicitly is not listed for it.